# AngularJS - How to get isolated directive scope variable in link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

See my code below.

directive:

```
app.directive("filterTree", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        controller: function($scope, $http){
            $scope.treeNodes = [];
            var filterItemsUrl = "/api/v1/users/userId/filter_nodes";
            $http.get(filterItemsUrl).success(function(response) {
                var filterItems = response["data"]["filter_nodes"];
                filterItems.map(function(item){
                    $scope.treeNodes.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        pId: item.pid,
                        name: item.name,
                        open: item.open,
                        checked: item.checked
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller){
            var setting = {
                check: {
                    enable: true
                },
                data: {
                    simpleData: {
                        enable: true
                    }
                }
            };

            $.fn.zTree.init(element, setting, scope.treeNodes);
        }
    };
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="ztree" filter-tree="" id="filterTree"></ul>
```

`scope.treeNodes` is not accessible in my link function. How can I access this isolates scope variable in my link function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell link function to wait until controller function executed completely?

You need to use the httpPromise to **chain** execution of `$.fn.zTree.init`.

```
app.directive("filterTree", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        controller: function($scope, $http, $element){
            $scope.treeNodes = [];
            var filterItemsUrl = "/api/v1/users/userId/filter_nodes";
            //save httpPromise
            var httpPromise = $http.get(filterItemsUrl);
            //chain from httpPromise
            httpPromise.then(function(response) {
                var filterItems = response.data["data"]["filter_nodes"];
                filterItems.map(function(item){
                    $scope.treeNodes.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        pId: item.pid,
                        name: item.name,
                        open: item.open,
                        checked: item.checked
                    });
                });
                //return treeNodes for chaining zTree.init
                return $scope.treeNodes;
            }).then (function onFulfilled (treeNodes) {
                var setting = {
                    check: { enable: true },
                    data: { simpleData: { enable: true }
                };
                //execute zTree.init
                $.fn.zTree.init($element, setting, treeNodes);
            })
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller){
        }
    };
});
```

The `$q` service waits for fulfillment of the promise before executing the `onFulfilled` function of the `.then` method. In this way, the execution of `zTree.init` gets properly delayed.

For more information on chaining promises, see the [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

Also notice the injection of the local `$element` in the controller function.

For more information on controller locals, see the [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-).

Also the `.success` and `.error` methods of the `$http` service have been **deprecated**. For more information on that, see the [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice).

Comment: Thanks a lot @georgeawg. Let me try this out. This is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the directive you have created doesn't have isolate scope but has inherited scope, that is, it shares the scope with the parent controller.

For isolate scope, you have to define the scope of the directive as being an object like this:

```
scope: {
    //your binded attributes here
}
```

For accessing `$scope.treeNodes`, pass it as an attribute:

```
<ul class="ztree" filter-tree tree-nodes="treeNodes" id="filterTree"></ul>
```

And bind it in your directive:

```
restrict: 'AE',
scope: {
    tree_nodes: '=treeNodes' //'=' for two way binding
}
```

`scope.tree_nodes` is now binded two way to `$scope.treeNodes` of your controller.

Comment: I don't have treeNodes defined in my controller. I want to do that with in my directive.

Comment: Same solution, whenever you alter scope.tree_nodes, the corresponding value '$scope.treeNodes' will also change in the controller.

Comment: Oh! Then I might need some other solution. I want to keep this completely isolated from my main controller.

Comment: for that you can use one way binding using '@'. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want

Comment: I want to add a tree in my page. I am using zTree library for that. Tree nodes are dynamically fetching from server. There will be multiple trees with different nodes. So I want to fetch tree nodes from server when ever a `filter-tree` directive is called. I will have a type attribute for `filter-tree` directive to build api URL.

Answer (score 0):

The scope.treeNodes is accessible in the link function, please have a look at the following plunk ([Hyperlink here][1]).

The problem here is that you are doing an HTTP request in controller which is asynchronous request, by the time the data is loaded the link function is already executed that is why the data is not loaded.

You need to rewrite this in such a way so that when Link function is executed the data is loaded by http request before that.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. How can I do that? Is there any way to tell link function to wait until controller function executed completely?